# i am getting a error when i am running the flask application with python to plot graphs on web ui

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I aim to plot a line graph on the webpage using flask and charts.js I am just a beginner so I followed the link(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E2hytuQvLlE&lc=UgzWBrS2GEx1BnNgs2V4AaABAg) to implement this program but it not working the error on the webpage is mentioned at the end of the question.

This is my python code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/home")
def home():
    plot_data = [
        ("3-01-2020", 6),
        ("3-02-2020", 13),
        ("3-03-2020", 14),
        ("3-04-2020", 41),
        ("1-05-2020", 10),
        ("3-06-2020", 0),
        ("3-07-2020", 16),
        ("3-08-2020", 10),
        ("3-09-2020", 17),
        ("3-10-2020", 19),
    ]
    labels = []
    values = []
    for row in plot_data:
        labels.append(row[1])
        values.append(row[0])

    return render_template('graph.html', lables=labels, values=values)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chart view</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.3.2/chart.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id = "voltage_graph" width="900" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById("voltage_graph").getContext("2d");
        var lineChart = new Chart(ctx,{
            type: "line",
            data:{
                labels: {{labels | safe}}
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "BMS_CELL_01_voltage",
                        data:  {{values | safe}},
                        fill : false,
                        borderColor:"rgb(75,192,192)",
                        lineTension: 0.1
                    }
                ]
            },
            Options:{
                responsive: false
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my terminal output

```
C:\Users\rohit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe C:/Users/rohit/PycharmProjects/flask-projects/applicaton.py
 * Serving Flask app 'application (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 275-482-683
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

[image]

**when I run this all I get is an error on the website stating as above**
any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: `@app.route("/home")` route is `/home` and you put `127.0.0.1:5000` it should be `127.0.0.1:5000/home`

Comment: but i am getting a blank screen now

Comment: right click and click on `view page resource` and check if you are getting the page or not.

Comment: i am getting the page but it says      Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' home:18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues in the code you posted:

- `lables=` is mispelled in `app.py`, should be `labels=`
- `labels.append(row[1])` should use `row[0]`, assuming you want the dates to be used as labels (and vice versa, where `values` should use `row[1]` instead)
- `labels: {{labels | safe}}` is missing a comma at the end

Once you fix these issues, your graph will show up when you navigate to `localhost:5000/home`.

---

**EDIT:** For completeness, here is the working code. In `app.py`:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/home")
def home():
    plot_data = [
        ("3-01-2020", 6),
        ("3-02-2020", 13),
        ("3-03-2020", 14),
        ("3-04-2020", 41),
        ("1-05-2020", 10),
        ("3-06-2020", 0),
        ("3-07-2020", 16),
        ("3-08-2020", 10),
        ("3-09-2020", 17),
        ("3-10-2020", 19),
    ]
    labels = []
    values = []
    for row in plot_data:
        labels.append(row[0])
        values.append(row[1])

    print(labels)
    print(values)
    return render_template('graph.html', labels=labels, values=values)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And in `templates/graph.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chart view</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.3.2/chart.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id = "voltage_graph" width="900" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById("voltage_graph").getContext("2d");
        var lineChart = new Chart(ctx,{
            type: "line",
            data:{
                labels: {{labels | safe}},
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "BMS_CELL_01_voltage",
                        data:  {{values | safe}},
                        fill : false,
                        borderColor:"rgb(75,192,192)",
                        lineTension: 0.1
                    }
                ]
            },
            Options:{
                responsive: false
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```